# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'FIREBASE_DATABASE_EMULATOR_HOST' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, aws, amazon-s3

En la imagen se ve el error que me aparece en consola, este error me apareció después de definir de una variable para usar los servicios de `AWS(S3)`, ya que me salia otro error por no estar definida, la variable que definí fue en el `tsconfig` y me dejo de salir el otro error, lo quiero hacer es conectar `aws s3` para subir las fotos de los artículos de la app ya que estos pesan demasiado, ya tengo creado un `bucket` y seguí los pasos necesarios para poder enlazarlo de manera adecuado.

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
       declare var swal : any;
        import * as firebase from 'firebase';
        import * as S3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';


        @Component({
       })
        export class ProductosVerComponent implements OnInit {
          public selectedFile: any;
          bucket: S3 = new S3(
            {
              accessKeyId: 'AKIAUT7IXVID4CI4XZVD',
              secretAccessKey: '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',
              region: 'us-east-1'
            }
          );        
        }
```

Comment: Puedes poner la documentación que estas siguiendo? Para darte una mano.

Comment: Muchas gracias angel pero ya lo solucione, era una incompatibilidad en una version de firebase